# How to extract the displayed name of an entity

Tags: associations, boxes, entity

Entities are typically displayed in their elided form:

[image]

It's useful when exploring the output of `EntityList` to have access to the canonical name of the `Entity` as well as the "displayed" name of the `Entity`.

How can entities be translated so that in the case of `Entity["HistoricalEvent", "AlanTuring"]` we are returned:

```
<|"EntityName" -> "AlanTuring", 
"DisplayedName" -> "Alan Turing writes his influential paper On Computable Numbers"|>
```

## Solution

The solution of @Karsten 7 was accepted as it is both considerably more terse and efficient:

@Kartsen 7:

```
historicalEntityNames = <|"EntityName" -> #1, 
      "DisplayedName" -> #2|> & @@@ 
    Transpose[{CanonicalName@historicalEvents, 
      CommonName@historicalEvents}]; // AbsoluteTiming
{0.212431, Null}
```

@martinjohnhadley

```
historicalEntityNames = 
   ToBoxes /@ historicalEvents /. 
    TemplateBox[{name_, 
       RowBox[{_, _, RowBox[{_, ",", entity_}], _}], _, _}, 
      "Entity"] :> <|"EntityName" -> TextWords[entity][[1]], 
      "DisplayedName" -> 
       StringRiffle@TextWords@name|>; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{12.9818, Null}*)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the same

```
historicalEvents = EntityList[Entity["HistoricalEvent"]];
```

as in the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118972/18476) by [Martin John Hadley](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1952/martin-john-hadley).

One can generate the same `historicalEntityNames` using

```
historicalEntityNames = <|"EntityName" -> #1, "DisplayedName" -> #2|> & @@@ 
 Transpose[{CanonicalName@historicalEvents, CommonName@historicalEvents}]
```

or

```
historicalEntityNames = 
 AssociationThread[{"EntityName", "DisplayedName"}, #] & /@ 
  Transpose[Through[{CanonicalName, CommonName}[historicalEvents]]]
```

---

Or more directly:

```
historicalEntityNames = 
 Query[All, <|"EntityName" -> CanonicalName@#, "DisplayedName" -> CommonName@#|> &]@
  EntityList[Entity["HistoricalEvent"]]
```

or

```
historicalEntityNames = Query[All, {CanonicalName, CommonName} /*
    <|"EntityName" -> First, "DisplayedName" -> Last|>]@
  EntityList[Entity["HistoricalEvent"]]
```

---

For a single `Entity` using for example

```
EntityValue[Entity["HistoricalEvent", "AlanTuring"], {"CanonicalName", "Name"}, 
  "PropertyAssociation"]
```

> [image: out]

might be useful.

Comment: `CommonName` - how I've needed you. Thanks!

Comment: `EntityValue[
 EntityClass["HistoricalEvent", All], {"CanonicalName", 
  "Name"}, "PropertyAssociation"]` or `EntityValue[
 Entity["HistoricalEvent"], {"CanonicalName", 
  "Name"}, "PropertyAssociation"]` don't return anything within reasonable time.

Comment: I've never trusted "PropertyAssociation" so not really surprised - but this is a very comprehensive answer now, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

All of the `HistoricalEvents` in the Wolfram Knowledgebase are accessible as follows:

```
historicalEvents = EntityList[Entity["HistoricalEvent"]];
```

Using `ToBoxes` the display form of the `Entity` can be seen:

```
ToBoxes[historicalEvents[[1]]]
(*TemplateBox[{"\"Alan Turing writes his influential paper, \\\"On \
Computable Numbers\\\"\"", 
  RowBox[{"Entity", "[", 
    RowBox[{"\"HistoricalEvent\"", ",", "\"AlanTuring\""}], "]"}], 
  "\"Entity[\\\"HistoricalEvent\\\", \\\"AlanTuring\\\"]\"", 
  "\"historical event\""}, "Entity"]*)
```

Using the following `ReplaceAll` pattern the entity names and descriptions can be returned easily:

```
historicalEntityNames = 
  ToBoxes /@ historicalEvents /. 
   TemplateBox[{name_, 
      RowBox[{_, _, RowBox[{_, ",", entity_}], _}], _, _}, 
     "Entity"] :> <|"EntityName" -> TextWords[entity][[1]], 
     "DisplayedName" -> StringRiffle@TextWords@name|>;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is usually possible to query properties of entities.  That makes it easier to discover how to extract information.

[image]

Code:

```
ent = Entity["HistoricalEvent", "AlanTuring"]

ent["Properties"]

InputForm[%]

ent["Name"]
```

(I'm not really sure why `ent` doesn't display properly on my machine...)

Comment: I now can find no evidence of this, but I'm convinced that previously I've seen entities without the property "name". Your method also required an internet connection, which is absurd when the information is already contained within the `TemplateBox` anyhow. It's a shame that this isn't implemented in the same way as `CommonName` and allowed to use the local cache